# Do modern video game consoles sandbox games?

Tags: malware, sandbox

If for example there is a game, that is specifically designed to try to get control of your game console or to be able to provide the user of the game control over their system and somehow got onto the console's respective official store (thus is easily install-able for a lot of people).

How much could it do? Are the games sand-boxed and are denied access to certain abilities? If so what are they denied? How many historical vulnerabilities have there been for such a thing?

Or is the game able to just do anything like ancient consoles could I think.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, Xbox One runs a hypervisor as the host OS and uses a virtual machine to run the games. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_system_software#Xbox_One_and_Xbox_Series_X/S

Comment: Which game console? There are quite a few out there...